# package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 2383 pos 12: 'attached': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, get

```
package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 2383 pos 12: 'attached': is not true.
package:flutter/…/rendering/object.dart:1
The relevant error-causing widget was
GetMaterialApp
lib\main.dart:70
```

I am getting this issue in recent times. Any idea on this issue?

Comment: show some code how you have implemented

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.